# Using Cypress drop down select values are not happening

Tags: cypress

How can I select the `dropdown` values using Cypress, it is build on angular page. By default the select field is displaying as below. First option click on the drop down but not value, I have tried eq(1), eq(2)..but not working yet.

[image]

I have tried the below options in cypress but these are not working;

**Option : 1**

```js
cy.get('.mat-select-value > span').eq(0).then((option)=>{
  cy.wrap(option).eq(0).click();
})
```

**Option 2:**

```js
cy.get('.mat-select-value > span').contains("Phase 4 - Boond ").click();
```

// Attached the html:

[image]

Comment: What part doesn't work? 1. Opening the dropdown? 2. Selecting the wished option?

If it is the first one, you are clicking on the incorrect element. You need to click on the element that triggers the dropdown to open.

Comment: First option is opening the drop down but not selecting the value

Comment: @Mr.J. Option 1 open the drop drown selection box, but its doesn't select value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to try this:

```js
cy.get('.mat-select-value > span').eq(0).click() // to open the drop down
cy.get('.mat-option').contains('Phase 4 - Boond').click() // to click the actual option
```

Comment: Its says `mat-select-panel-wrap', but never found it.`

Comment: hmm, well you can replace the first line with the line you were already using to open up the drop down. The second line is the thing that should fix your problem

Comment: ` cy.get('.mat-select-value > span').eq(0).click().then((option) => {
        // After click, mat-select should contain the text of the selected option
        cy.get('.mat-option').contains('Phase 4 - Boond').click()    
      });`

Comment: No luck for me : Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: mat-option, but never found it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the click() doesn't work as you would expect, in this case you can also try the trigger('click) for the option selection.

like:

cy.get('your-selector').trigger('click')