# Mat-Select drop down not working with Cypress

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, cypress, e2e-testing

Trying to click on the drop down which is `mat-select` from Angular.

HTML Code which can be seen in browser console:

[image]

I already tried:

1. [Using Cypress drop down select values are not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506285/using-cypress-drop-down-select-values-are-not-happening)
2. [Selecting options from Mat-select using cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520834/selecting-options-from-mat-select-using-cypress)

The actual HTML code looks like this:

[image]

Following the screenshot of Drop down item I want to select (Stage E2E)

[image]

Note: there is not error thrown for click, but on UI I never see the click and later it get following error -

[image]

Comment: Please add your version of the code that you tried along with any errors that you got.

Comment: @AlapanDas ,for the click on drop-down element, which I am using `[placeholder='Team Member']` in this case, never gives error. But on UI it never clicks

Comment: How about you use `force: true` like `cy.get('[placeholder='Team Member']').first().click({force: true})` ?

Comment: Nope, did that already. Doesn't work.

Comment: How about changing the locator to `cy.get('mat-select[placeholder='Team Member']').eq(0).click()`

Comment: The error message indicates it can't find the option element. I would check the DOM (not the HTML source) to see if the selector you're using for the option is correct.

Comment: @SydneyY, 1. Click doesn't show error, but on UI click action is not seen. 2. What locator do you suggest to select the droop down items?

Comment: Sorry, if I knew I'd write you an answer. In css the selector would be `mat-select .mat-select-value-text span`

Answer (score 1):

Experience has taught us that it is always better to explicitly ID any elements you want to test with Cypress, and this is especially true for Angular Material components.

In order to test our mat-selects we would use something like:

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>{{ 'common.team-member' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select id="e2e-team-member-select" 
              formControlName="teamMember" multiple>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let member of teamMembers; let i = index"
      [value]="member.id"
      [id]="'e2e-team-member-' + i"
     >
       {{ member.name }}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

../cypress/integrations/showing.ts

```js
// set team-member 4
cy.get('#e2e-team-member-select').click();
cy.get('#e2e-team-member-4').click();
cy.wait('@loadMembers'); // wait for backend
cy.get('body').click(); // close select if multi
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, Angular is not actually using a `placeholder` attribute to show the text you want.

Instead it uses a `label` positioned over the select with css `position: absolute`.

**Angular select example page**

This is the group of elements (simplified) - `mat-select` and `label` are siblings.

```html
<div class="mat-form-field-infix">
  <mat-select role="combobox" class="mat-select">
    <div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger">
      <div class="mat-select-value">
        <span class="mat-select-placeholder"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper">
        <div class="mat-select-arrow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
  <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper">
    <label class="mat-form-field-label">
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

You want to test the text content of the `mat-select`, but target it via the label text.

```js
cy.viewport(1200, 1000)
cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview')

cy.contains('span', 'Favorite food')
  .siblings('mat-select')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('be.empty')

// open the select
cy.contains('span', 'Favorite food')
  .siblings('mat-select')
  .click()                      

// choose option
cy.contains('mat-option', 'Tacos').click()

// check the select text has option value
cy.contains('span', 'Favorite food')
  .siblings('mat-select')
  .should('contain', 'Tacos')
```

---

**Your select**

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Team Member')
  .siblings('mat-select')
  .click()

cy.contains('mat-option', 'Stage E2E').click()

cy.contains('span', 'Team Member')
  .siblings('mat-select')
  .should('contain', 'Stage E2E')
```